# UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY does it return the correct number of affected_rows?

Tags: php, mysql, myisam, database

I need to make a lot of `UPDATE` and I don't need to read the table often.

So I thought of using `UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY` but does it return the correct number of `affected_rows()` ?

Or considering it's not instantly committed it can't know how many records will be affected?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY table SET view = view + 1 WHERE id = 123");
echo mysql_affected_rows();
```

Comment: it seems no one use this update low_priority lol

Answer (score -1):

Yes it returns the affected rows number, LOW_PRIORITY doesn't affect this part.

> With the LOW_PRIORITY keyword, execution of the UPDATE is delayed until no other clients are reading from the table. This affects only storage engines that use only table-level locking (such as MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE).

Comment: I have MyISAM and by reading your quote it cannot return the right number.

Comment: @yes123 - where does that quote mention `affected_rows()` at all?

Comment: `execution of the UPDATE is delayed until no other clients are reading from the table`